# Standard limits not working on this particular question

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

I have this question and its been troubling me for so long. I try to use the standard trig. limits but that just fails everytime and I get the answer as $\infty$.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x+x\cos(x)-3\sin(x)}{x^4\sin(x)}$$

note: I have posted the question by already taking the lcm since i didnt think it would matter (hopefully).

I even checked out some limit calculators but all they show is l hopital rule which is very tiring, but they end up with the right answer which is $1/60$.

**More than the answer im trying to figure out why standard limits fail here?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "standard" limits?

Comment: Are you familiar with Taylor Series?

Comment: By standard limits i mean the one like sinx/x, 1-cosx/x ,etc

Comment: The easiest approach is to use Taylor series. If you want to use L'Hospital's Rule then first replace the denominator with $x^5$ via standard limits and then apply L'Hospital's Rule. At most two applications of L'Hospital's Rule will be needed.

Comment: Also standard limits don't fail here, but are rather insufficient to produce the final answer. You can use L'Hospital's Rule and standard limits together without much difficulty.

Comment: What do you mean by insufficient?

Comment: Insufficient means "not sufficient" or "inadequate". If you believe that every limit can be evaluated by using standard limits then you need to change your belief. This is just one of the techniques and sometimes it may need to be combined with other techniques to get answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use L'Hôpital's rule.

Let $n(x) = 2x +x \cos x -3 \sin x$, $d(x) = x^4\sin x$.

Note that $n^{(k)}(0) = d^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for $k=1,2,3,4$.

However $n^{(5)}(0) = 2, d^{(5)}(0) = 120$.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can find this is by using the Taylor series expansions for $\cos x$ and $\sin x$.

Using the first few terms in each,
\begin{align*}
\frac{2x + x \cos x - 3 \sin x}{x^4 \cdot \sin x} &= \frac{2x + x(1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + O(x^6)) - 3(x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + O(x^7))}{x^4(x + O(x^3))}\\
&= \frac{2x + x - \frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^5}{24} + O(x^7) - 3x + \frac{x^3}{2} - \frac{x^5}{40} + O(x^7)}{x^5 + O(x^7)}\\
&= \frac{\frac{x^5}{60} + O(x^7)}{x^5 + O(x^7)}\\
&= \frac{1}{60} + O(x^2)
\end{align*}

As $x \to 0$, we get that the limit is $\boxed{\frac{1}{60}}$.

Comment: Im actually not too familiar with the taylor series, though i just know what it means.
Could you tell me what the "O" stands for?

Comment: You can read up on it here:  https://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf.